# How to responsively make a word with dashes go to next line instead of breaking?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a word with dashes go to the next line on smaller devices.

I tried different properties like word-wrap, hyphens. But it doesn't work for me.

codepen demo: https://codepen.io/johnthecoder/pen/MWgKNYe

or

```
HTML

<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome to my-word-with-dashes</h1>
</div>

CSS

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

I want the word with dashes to go the the next line.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget you are using fixed `width` of `400px` for `.container` instead of `media query` for mobile devices.

Try to change `width` for `.container` on mobile devices (usually `< 480px`).

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Now, if you want words with hyphens that don't break, you can use [`Unicode Character Non-breaking Hyphen`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm) (`U+2011`) (`&#8209`):

```
<h1>Welcome to my‑word‑with‑dashes</h1>
```

Another option to avoid breaking the word with hyphens is to put it inside a `span` with `white-space: nowrap` property:

```
<h1>Welcome to <span style="white-space: nowrap">my-word-with-dashes</span></h1>
```

Avoid `<nobr>`:

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers,
>   its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to
>   avoid using it.

Comment: I edited the code with max-width. If you reduce the window the word break for each dashes. I want it to go all next line

Comment: Check the second part of my answer. You may use that character ( ‑ ) instead of the common hyphen ( - ).

Comment: @Azametzin what's the differences between the two dashes. How did you get the "uncommon" one ?

Comment: I knew that there are special characters that prevent an automatic line break at their positions. So, you can search and find some of them. For example, there is the **non-breaking space** (" ") as well

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with white-space:nowrap;

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center; 
}
.nobr {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome to <span class="nobr">my-word-with-dashes</span></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as the CSS answers, you can replace the hyphens `-` with a non-breaking hyphen `&#8209;`

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome to my-word-with-dashes</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome to my&#8209;word&#8209;with&#8209;dashes</h1>
</div>
```